# In scala /: method, why put the first parameter in front when invoke

Tags: scala

The methods of List in scala /:

```
def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

The invocation of foldLeft is:

```
(List(1, 7, 2, 9) foldLeft 0) (_ + _)
```

The invocation of /: is:

```
(0 /: List(1, 7, 2, 9)) (_ + _)
```

That 0 is actually the first parameter of the method, why is the 0 of the method put in front, instead of just like foldLeft in the back

Answer (score 0):

Method name that end with a colon `:` are right associative in Scala, that is when they are used in operator syntax, they are invoked on the object to the right of them with the object to the left of them as a parameter.

So your invocation

```
(0 /: List(1, 7, 2, 9)) (_ + _)
```

is basically the same as

```
List(1, 7, 2, 9)./:(0) (_ + _ )
```

The first on allows a nicer syntax if you are used to what the semantics are.

Comment: oh~~ I know, just like  1 :: 2 :: Nil

Comment: but, (List(1, 7, 2, 9) /: 0)(_ + _ ) is not correct, why?

Comment: The compiler would look for a /: method on 0 which doesn't exist.

Comment: And it's *technically* the same as: `{ val __new_fresh_name__ = 0; List(1, 7, 2, 9)./:(__new_fresh_name__) (_ + _)`. (Order of evaluation is still left-to-right, which can be observed if the parameter is a by-name-parameter or if the arguments have side-effects.)